# Js-beautify wrap inline comments near css rules

Tags: html, css, js-beautify

I have a small issue with [js beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/) when I try to format my scss codebase.

### Input

The code looked like this before beautification:

```css
.hero-about {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .4),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)), url("../../images/backgrounds/team.png") center/cover; /* 1 */
  height: .1rem; /* 2 */
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

### Expected Output

The code should have looked like this after beautification (same):

```css
.hero-about {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .4),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)), url("../../images/backgrounds/team.png") center/cover; /* 1 */
  height: .1rem; /* 2 */
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

### Actual Output

The  code actually looked like this after beautification, you can note that beautify wrap the inline comments, and obviously I don't want this ugly behavior.

```css
.hero-about {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url("../../images/backgrounds/team.png") center/cover;
  /* 1 */
  height: .1rem;
  /* 2 */
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

---

### Steps to Reproduce

Simply copy the css code, and try to run js-beautify **no configuration is needed**.

### Environment

OS: Windows 10 Home 6/03/2020 18363.720

---

### Settings

```
{
   "indent_size": 2, 
"end_with_new_line": true
}
```

*Please note: This ugly behavior is independent from the configuration file, you can notice it with any configuration*.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guessed a small workaround for that.

In my `gulpfile.js` I wrote (thank you [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace)!):

`.pipe(replace(";\n  /* ", "; /* "))`

This, during the SCSS gulp compilation, will fix the problem caused by js-beautify. It will replace the "\n" (line break) with a " " (space).

**Hope it help!**

---